# Переключение между двумя фрагментами MainActivity с помощью BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, bottom-navigation-view

На главном Activity есть BottomNavigationView и еще 2 layout файла фрагментов. Как реализовать переключение между этими фрагментами, чтобы при этом оставался видимым и правильно функционировал BottomNavigatonView? Видел несколько вариантов реализации, что называется, "на словах", но хотелось бы чтобы объяснил понимающий человек на примере. Буду очень рад :)

Comment: вот вам [пример](http://www.androprogrammer.com/2016/12/bottom-navigation-view-with-fragments.html). Если что то не понятно в реализации конкретно, задавайте вопрос именно по этой проблеме. "Как cделать фрагменты с переключением BNV" - вопрос на мой взгляд слишком общий. Впрочем может у кого то и появится желание все это расписывать на примере.

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо, буду разбираться ;)

Comment: @pavloff понял насколько легка моя идея в реализации. Ничего кроме метода changeFragment из данного вами примера пока что не пригодилось) И то переработал немного)) Т.к. у меня два пункта всего лишь) Может в будущем пригодится ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В layout-разметке `Activity`, внутри которой вы разместили `BottomNavigationView`, поместите `FrameLayout`, присвойте ему id. Он будет служить контейнером для фрагментов, между которыми вы будете переключаться.

Дальше определяете слушатель нажатий меню:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                changeFragment(firstFragment);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                changeFragment(secondFragment);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

И метод, который будет менять фрагменты в контейнере:

```
 public void changeFragment(Fragment fragment) {
     getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment) // id вашего FrameLayout
            .commit();
 }
```